# Missing MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS folder

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I seem to be missing my

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sql SERVER\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS 
folder. I have reinstalled SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 but still do not have it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have installed SQL Server 2008 as the default instance and not the named instance. When you install using the SQLExpress install, you normally get a named instance. When you install using the 'regular' SQL Server installation media, you normally get a "default", or unnamed, instance.

Comment: Ok, after installing the SQLEXPRESS, I now have it.  But I can't connect to my SQL instance.  I checked my services, and the SQLEXPRESS service isn't started and cannot be started.

Comment: Look in the windows event log to see why the service isn't starting.